# print several strings using for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to apply for loop in the print statement in Python 3.7.

For example

```
string1="Liverpool is always alone"
string2="Manchester United is the best team in the world"
string3="Tottenham Hotspur is for losers"
string4="Leicester City is overrated"

for i in range(1,5):
    print(string%i.find(" is"))  # <---this is the problem
```

My ultimate aim is to get

```
9
17
17
14
```

Sure, I can store the results in a list and then print the results like this:

```
 results=[string1.find(" is"),
          string2.find(" is"),
          string3.find(" is"),
          string4.find(" is")]

    for i in range(1,4):
        print(results[i])
```

But it will be troublesome especially when the number of string becomes too much.

Please suggest a way to print the multiple strings using for loop.

I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: I would contest that declaring variables `string1, string2, ...` is *more* troublesome than storing all the strings in a list called `strings` (without declaring the variables). If you store all of them in a list, you can simply have `for string in strings: print string.find(' is')`

Comment: btw `range(1,4)` will iterate on 1,2,3 only

Comment: @slider fair point. Have my upvote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the strings in a list:

```
statements = [
    "Liverpool is always alone",
    "Manchester United is the best team in the world",
    "Tottenham Hotspur is for losers",
    "Leicester City is overrated",
]
```

Then you can easily loop over them:

```
for s in statements:
    print(s.find(" is"))
```

Comment: I agree about the list, then just `[print(s.find(" is")) for s in statements]` to print

Comment: alright, I guess this is the closest I can ever get to concatenate integer with variable name in the print statement